# Whitespace in document has a bottom border remnant or some other line at the bottom of the whitespace

Tags: html, css, image

I have a webpage with two `<picture>` elements that each have `<a>` in front of them. The images are inline, next to each other. Whitespace is between these two elements (not sure why, but I'm fine with the small gap between them) and the whitespace itself has a little underscore or bottom-border type of characteristic to it. I don't want this little underscore to be visible.

Page viewable here: https://nohappynonsense.net/writtte

If I remove the `<a>` from each picture the little line goes away. But I want these images to have a link, so I'm not sure what else to try.

Also - sorry if my code looks like some horrible mess, I'm not a programmer or coder or anything.

Comment: [something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)